# C# and SQL Server deployment issue

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am deploying my database with a C# application but I am unable to connect to the database when I am installing the `setup.exe` file on different machine.

The error I get is:

> A network -related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL server.The server was not found or
>   was not accessible.Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connection.(provider:Named
>   pipes Provider,error:40- could not open a connection to SQL Server)

What should I do to overcome this?

Comment: What is your connection string?  It sounds like you can't hit the `servername[\instancename]` properly.

Comment: What code is used to connect?  Is SQL remote?

Comment: Last time I had a "named pipes provider error", it was a firewall issue (the rule that allows TCP connections for SQL Server was missing).
When SQL Server doesn't manage to use the default TCP provider, it tries to use named pipes.

Comment: Do you know if Port 1433 (or whatever port you are using for SQL Server) is being blocked?  http://serverfault.com/questions/26564/how-to-check-if-a-port-is-blocked-on-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be number of reasons. Most probable...either your connection string is not correct(which is most probable), or the instance you are trying to connect doesn't have Named Pipes enabled.

To check the later one go to Programs -> SQL Server {version} -> Configuration Tools -> SqlServer Configuration Manager -> find Client protocols and then find Named Pipes/TCP/IP and set it to Enabled